# Универсальный метод insert jdbc Java

Tags: java, jdbc

Подскажите, а можно ли с помощью дженериков сделать более универсальным это метод? Что бы можно было передать, любой другой объект, разобрать его и сохранить? Или даже список?

```
public static void insert(String url, String sql, User user) {
    try (
        final Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        final PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    ) {
      preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getName());
      preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getLogin());
      preparedStatement.setString(3, user.getPsw());
      preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
//вызываю метод

String sql = "INSERT INTO `user` (`name`, `login`, `psw`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
User user = new User("Name", "login", "123");

    insert(url, sql, user);
```

Comment: Смотрите в сторону `JPA`, `Hibernate`...

Comment: JPA тебе уже посоветовали, а если не хочешь, то некую универсальность можно сделать, если отказаться от убогого синтаксиса `?, ?, ?` и использовать `:name, :login, :psw`, парсить такую строку самому, заменяя токены на ? и запоминая имя проперти и номер подстановки. Потом в цикле для каждого номера проставлять значение, взятое по имени проперти. Так работает NamedParameterJdbcTemplate в Спринге

Comment: Или просто NamedParameterJdbcTemplate взять как легковесную альтернативу JPA

Comment: @Alexander Pavlov Спасибо, поюзаю библиотеку, хотел свою реализацию, исключительно в учебных целях.